# Getting the Probability Mass Function of Derived Random Variables

Tags: probability

Here is the problem:

[image]

Here is the solution:

[image]

Now, I did the solution on my own and I got the same answer except the last part. I just want to confirm that this is a typo in the solutions (looking at the rest of the solution, it does appear to be a typo).

Shouldn't the solution (labelled as (2) in the solution) have been:

${ q }^{ \frac { t+1 }{ 2 }  }(1-q)$

instead of:

${ q }^{ \frac { t-1 }{ 2 }  }(1-q)$

? It seems that the solution correctly derives x=(t+1)/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a typo. They have $P_T(t)=P_X((t+1)/2)$ so if you substitute $x=(t+1)/2$ into the function $P_X(x)$ in (a) you get

$$P_T(t) = q^{(t+1)/2 - 1}(1-q) = q^{(t-1)/2}(1-q).$$

If it's still unclear, you can take a specific example, such as $P_T(5)$. To get the outcome $T=5$ we need exactly $2$ failures (errors) followed by a success. The probability of this is therefore $q^2(1-q)$, which equals $q^{(5-1)/2}(1-q)$.